# Como puedo hacer para pasar los datos del fichero a int?

Tags: java, poo

En un fichero CSV se almacenan los resultados de una carrera con el formato nombre;segundos. El programa convertira estos datos en un ArrayList. Despues se le preguntará al usuario cuantos datos quiere ver (n) y se listaran los n participantes con el mejor tiempo; para eso se buscara al corredor con el menor tiempo y se elminará del ArrayList, hasta completar el listado.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int numero = 0;

    File f = new File("datos.dat");
    Scanner fichero = new Scanner(f);

    ArrayList<String> datos = new ArrayList();
    String linea;
    int t1=0;
    while (fichero.hasNext()) {
        linea = fichero.nextLine();
        if (datos.size()==0){
           datos.add(linea);
        } else {
           t1=Integer.parseInt(linea.substring(linea.indexOf(";")));

        }
    }
    System.out.println(t1);
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    numero = teclado.nextInt();
    numero = numero - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= numero; i++) {
        System.out.println(datos.get(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: Me suena a que quieres que te hagamos la tarea.

Comment: Estoy practicando,no tengo que entregar esto en ningún sitio.Me he quedado atascado ahí

Comment: Integer.parseInt(String);, ya lo probastes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para convertir un string a un entero se debe usar `Integer.parseInt();` pero a ti no te funcionaria puesto que no tienes separado el numero del nombre, si intentas convertir al que no sea un numero te saldrá un error: aca te dejo la solución al problema que tienes:

//Crea una clase que contendrá las partes de cada linea del archivo

```
class Carrera {

   private String nombre;
   private int segundos;

   public Carrera(String nombre, int segundos) {
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.segundos = segundos;
   }

   public String getNombre() {
      return nombre;
   }

   public int getSegundos() {
      return segundos;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "Carrera{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", segundos=" + segundos + '}';
   }
}
```

//Modifica tu código así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int numero = 0;

        File f = new File("datos.dat");
        Scanner fichero = new Scanner(f);

        ArrayList<Carrera> datos = new ArrayList();
        while (fichero.hasNext()) {

            String linea = fichero.nextLine();
            String columnas[] = linea.split(";");

            datos.add(new Carrera(columnas[0], Integer.parseInt(columnas[1])));
        }

        //Ordenamos de menos a mayor
        datos.sort(new Comparator<Carrera>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Carrera o1, Carrera o2) {
                return o1.getSegundos() - o2.getSegundos();
            }
        });

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        numero = teclado.nextInt();
        numero = numero - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i <= numero; i++) {
            System.out.println(datos.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!